# How can I change the value of one cell in Google sheets based on what is entered into another?

Tags: google-sheets

Using Google Sheets, I have a dropdown list of different actions, and each action has a different score associated with it.

Eg. Action a =  5 points, Action b = 7 points etc

How I can make Google Sheets automatically populate in column B the points associated with the action selected from the dropdown menu in column A?

Answer (score 2):

#### Nested IF statements

The formula

```
=if(A1="action a", 5, if(A1="action b", 7))
```

returns the value according to the content of cell A1.

#### Lookup table

Somewhere on the sheet, say in columns G:H (or on another sheet) make a table:

```
action a   5 
action b   7
```

Then the formula

```
=vlookup(A1, G:H, 2, false)
```

will return the value from column H that corresponds to the contents of A1. This approach is more extendable: when more actions are added, one only needs to expand the table in G:H. Also, column G can be used by the dropdown in A1 (use data validation for values in a range), so that the list of option is kept in one place.